# How can I define plain console output of a class object (vs. __str__)?

Tags: python

When defining my own class, I can overwrite the `__str__` to define its `print(my_class)` behavior. What do I have to do to overwrite the behavior when just calling an `my_class` object?

What I get:

```
> obj = my_class("ABC") # define
> print(obj)            # call with print
'my class with ABC'

> obj                   # call obj only
'<__console__.my_class object at 0x7fedf752398532d9d0>'
```

What I want (e.g. `obj` returning the same as `print(obj)` or some other manually defined text).

```
> obj                   # when obj is called plainly, I want to define its default
'my class with ABC (or some other default representation of the class object)'
```

With:

```
class my_class:

    def __init__(self, some_string_argument)
        self.some_string = some_string_argument

    def __str__(self): # 
        return f"my_class with {self.some_string}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magic method `__repr__` is the one. But this is discouraged.
In general `__str__` should be understandable for the end user and `__repr__` should return a string which when passed to `eval` would produce a valid instance of the object for which it's defined.

```py
class A:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "I'm A!"

a = A()
a # This will print "I'm A!"
```

What it should/could be:

```py
class A:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "A()"

a = A()
a_repr = a.__repr__()
b = eval(a_repr) # "b" is an instance of class A in this case
```

Comment: Or, at least, represents it as unambiguously as possible.